# String into a function call in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got a function name and want to call it inside Angular class (.ts file). `eval()` is not an option.

I have tried using `window[functionName]` , but it fails, guess because window context is outside the class

Any idea?

Comment: can you please provide more details on the component?

Comment: whats the error when it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy. For an example **`getData`** is your function name.

```
getData() {
  // your code goes here...
}

functionName = 'getData'; // function name as a string
```

**Now you can call this function like below:**

```
this[functionName]();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function is defined in a seperate class or service import it via the constructor and invoke the function. Like this

```
constructor(private serv: FunctionService){
   serv.your_function();
}
```

Call it inside the constructor or where ever it is appropriate depending on the context.
Hope this sounds meaningful.